# .net core convert null to empty string in response at ConfigureServices

Tags: api, asp.net-core, null, asp.net-core-3.1

I have API controller -**.net core 3.1**-

when I call method I get response object with its properties.

some of this might be null string.

How can I configure my API to return empty string instead of `null` ?

Can I do this in **Startup.cs** ?

**Edit**

I used this option:
`services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => { options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true; });`

but it'll hide null properties, which I don't want.

Comment: I think the easiest way is to set a default value for these properties:`public string Name { get; set; } = "";`

Comment: @Yinqiu I know that. but I want to do it in one place if I can

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: I would also like to know the answer to this. There must be an option to do this similarly to the ignore function stated in the question.

Comment: Found a solution in the end and added it as an answer to your question @Munt

Answer (score 2):

Okay so after having the same challenge and researching a bunch, I found out that you can absolutely convert NULLs to empty strings and still have these properties show in your frontend.

I used this other answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/67286291/11463515) as a reference and did the following.

### Step 1:

Create a new class file in the same directory as your `Startup.cs` file and name it `NullToEmptyStringConverter.cs` with the following code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace API
{
    public class NullToEmptyStringConverter : JsonConverter<string>
    {

        // Override default null handling
        public override bool HandleNull => true;
    
        public override string Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => 
            reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.Null ? "" : reader.GetString();

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            writer.WriteStringValue(value ?? "");
    }
}
```

Make sure that both your `Startup.cs` and `NullToEmptyStringConverter.cs` are using the same namespace!

### Step 2:

After creating the `NullToEmptyStringConverter.cs` file, you can now simply add the following to your `services.AddControllers()` method so it looks like this:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
          services.AddControllers()
                .AddJsonOptions(options => 
                {
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new NullToEmptyStringConverter());
                });
        }
```

And that should be it! With this, all string values that have the value `NULL` or `null` in your response will be replaced with `""`.