# System Text Json Converter for Null properties

Tags: c#, json, .net, system.text.json

I need to serialize and object into JSON to pass the payload to a Python script. The properties with `null` values in C# should have `None` value in the JSON passed to Python in order to work. I have created an JsonConverter to check if the value is `null` and write `None` instead. However is never called. As one of the properties that can be null is of type string (others can be float?, int?, etc) I have also created a JsonConverter:

```
public class NullJsonConverter : JsonConverter<string>
{
    public override string Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var jsonString = reader.GetString();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonString))
        {
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string>(jsonString, options);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            //Logic to convert from null to None
        }

        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```

However when I serialize an object that contains a property of type `string` the converter is only called when the property has a value.

This are the options that I'm using for the serialization:

```
return new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.Never,
    WriteIndented = true,
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    Converters =
    {
        new JsonStringEnumConverter(),
        new NullJsonConverter()
    }
};
```

What am I missing? How can I serialize in C# and object so the null properties are reflected as None in the JSON and when de-serializing back are converted back to null?

Comment: Override `HandleNull => true;` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67286291/3744182) to [System.Text.Json Serialize null strings into empty strings globally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59792850/3744182).  In fact I think this is a duplicate, agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overriding the `HandleNull` property and set it to `true`. Like described in this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/44006#issuecomment-719002484

```
public class NullJsonConverter : JsonConverter<string>
{
    public override bool HandleNull => true;

    public override string Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var jsonString = reader.GetString();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonString))
        {
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string>(jsonString, options);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            //Logic to convert from null to None
        }

        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```