# Serialize object to empty object {} instead of null with System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, .net, system.text.json

Using:

- .net 8
- System.Text.Json serializer.

Let's say I have a two classes defined like this:

```
public class SampleClass
{
    public SampleClassDetail? FirstProperty { get; set; }
    public SampleClassDetail? SecondProperty { get; set; }
}

public class SampleClassDetail
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And an instance of `SampleClass` :

```
SampleClass sample = new()
{
    FirstProperty = new SampleClassDetail { MyProperty = 1 }
};
```

Then I want to serialize it with `System.Text.Json`:
`string serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(sample);`

This produces:

```
{
  "FirstProperty": {
    "MyProperty": 1
  },
  "SecondProperty": null
}
```

But I would the null to be treated like: `"SecondProperty": {}`

I've tried creating a CustomJson Converter and adding it to the options:

```
public class SampleClassDetailConverter : JsonConverter<SampleClassDetail?>
{
    public override SampleClassDetail? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, SampleClassDetail? value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
        else
        {
            var newOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions(options);
            newOptions.Converters.Remove(this);
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, newOptions);
        }
    }
}

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.Converters.Add(new SampleClassDetailConverter());

string serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(sample, options);
```

But still getting the same.

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PsXrxt)

Comment: Converters are only called if there is an object to be converted, and not for `null`. Besides that, why would you want this? Is there a specific requirement on the receiving end to do so? It seems contrary to what every serializer I ever used is doing.

Comment: @PeterB it's a requirement from client for their print to output from the API I'm working on... for me it doesn't make sense and I should either ignore the property or returning null... but they want it to be {}

Comment: You could try doing a string replace on the output: `return json.Replace(": null", ": {}");`

Comment: You can create custom converter for `SampleClass`.

Comment: Override [`HandleNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1.handlenull) and return `true` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67286291/3744182) to [System.Text.Json Serialize null strings into empty strings globally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59792850/3744182): `public override bool HandleNull => true;`.  Does that fully answer your question, or do you need more specific help?

Comment: Forked fiddle showing `public override bool HandleNull => true;` here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2Znuye.

Comment: @dbc thanks! if you want, post it as answer so I can accept it