# Custom serialization of null values in Asp.net core WebApi

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, system.text.json

I have to change the default json serialization/deserialization  of an object following these rules:

1. When the C# object is null , it has to be serialize to json object with Id equals 0.
2. When the json object has id equals 0 , it has to be deserialize to C# object with null value.

I try this:

```
public class EntityConverter : JsonConverter<EventDefinition>
{
    public override EventDefinition Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        EventDefinition result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<EventDefinition>(ref reader, options);
        if (result.EventDefinitionId == 0)
            return null;
        else return result;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, EventDefinition value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            value = new EventDefinition();
            value.EventDefinitionId = 0;
            writer.WriteStringValue(JsonSerializer.Serialize(value));
        }
        else
            writer.WriteStringValue(JsonSerializer.Serialize(value));
    }
}
```

I need to replace `writer.WriteStringValue` beacuse it writes the whole object as a string and what I need is to continue with the normal serialization of the object after the modification. How can I achieved this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.NET 5** allows custom converters to handle `null` if they choose.  From *[How to write custom converters for JSON serialization (marshalling) in .NET: Handle null values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to#handle-null-values)*:

> To enable a custom converter to handle null for a reference or value type, override [`JsonConverter<T>.HandleNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1.handlenull) to return true.

Thus in `EntityConverter` you need to add

```
public override bool HandleNull => true;
```

However, when you do you will encounter a second problem, namely that, in `Write()`, you are writing the serialized JSON for `EventDefinition` as a double-serialized string value, rather than as an object.  How can it be serialized as an object (with `null` replaced) instead?  If you have applied `EntityConverter` as either:

- A `[JsonConverter]` applied to a property.
- A converter added to the [`Converters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.converters) collection.

Then you can enhance the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65430421/3744182) from *[How to use default serialization in a custom System.Text.Json JsonConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65430420/3744182)* to include `HandleNull` as follows:

```
public class EntityConverter : DefaultConverterFactory<EventDefinition>
{
    protected override bool HandleNull => true;
    
    protected override EventDefinition Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions modifiedOptions, JsonConverter<EventDefinition> defaultConverter)
    {
        var result = base.Read(ref reader, typeToConvert, modifiedOptions, defaultConverter);
        return result?.EventDefinitionId == 0 ? null : result;
    }
    
    protected override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, EventDefinition value, JsonSerializerOptions modifiedOptions, JsonConverter<EventDefinition> defaultConverter) 
    {
        value ??= new EventDefinition { EventDefinitionId = 0 };
        base.Write(writer, value, modifiedOptions, defaultConverter);
    }
}

public abstract class DefaultConverterFactory<T> : JsonConverterFactory
{
    class NullHandlingDefaultConverter : DefaultConverter
    {
        public NullHandlingDefaultConverter(JsonSerializerOptions options, DefaultConverterFactory<T> factory) : base(options, factory) { }
        public override bool HandleNull => true;
    }
    
    class DefaultConverter : JsonConverter<T>
    {
        readonly JsonSerializerOptions modifiedOptions;
        readonly DefaultConverterFactory<T> factory;
        readonly JsonConverter<T> defaultConverter;

        public DefaultConverter(JsonSerializerOptions options, DefaultConverterFactory<T> factory)
        {
            this.factory = factory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
            this.modifiedOptions = options.CopyAndRemoveConverter(factory.GetType());
            this.defaultConverter = (JsonConverter<T>)modifiedOptions.GetConverter(typeof(T));
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options) => factory.Write(writer, value, modifiedOptions, defaultConverter);

        public override T Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => factory.Read(ref reader, typeToConvert, modifiedOptions, defaultConverter);
    }

    protected virtual T Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions modifiedOptions, JsonConverter<T> defaultConverter)
        => defaultConverter.ReadOrSerialize<T>(ref reader, typeToConvert, modifiedOptions);

    protected virtual void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions modifiedOptions, JsonConverter<T> defaultConverter) 
        => defaultConverter.WriteOrSerialize(writer, value, modifiedOptions);

    protected virtual bool HandleNull => false;

    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => typeof(T) == typeToConvert;

    public override JsonConverter CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => HandleNull ? new NullHandlingDefaultConverter(options, this) : new DefaultConverter(options, this);
}

public static class JsonSerializerExtensions
{
    public static JsonSerializerOptions CopyAndRemoveConverter(this JsonSerializerOptions options, Type converterType)
    {
        var copy = new JsonSerializerOptions(options);
        for (var i = copy.Converters.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            if (copy.Converters[i].GetType() == converterType)
                copy.Converters.RemoveAt(i);
        return copy;
    }

    public static void WriteOrSerialize<T>(this JsonConverter<T> converter, Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (converter != null)
            converter.Write(writer, value, options);
        else
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, options);
    }

    public static T ReadOrSerialize<T>(this JsonConverter<T> converter, ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (converter != null)
            return converter.Read(ref reader, typeToConvert, options);
        else
            return (T)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(ref reader, typeToConvert, options);
    }
}
```

And serialize a `List<EventDefinition> events` as follow:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new EntityConverter() },
    WriteIndented = true, // If you want
};

var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(events, options);
```

Notes:

- **In .NET Core 3.x `HandleNull` is not available**; [`JsonConverter<T>.Write()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1.write?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_Serialization_JsonConverter_1_Write_System_Text_Json_Utf8JsonWriter__0_System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_) will never be passed a null value in that version.  Thus, in that version you would need to adopt a different approach, such as adding a custom converter for the containing type(s) or serializing [DTOs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) instead of "real" objects.

  Json.NET also will never call call its [`JsonConverter.WriteJson()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_WriteJson.htm) for a null value so the the two serializers are consistent in that limitation in 3.x, see *[How to force JsonConverter.WriteJson() to be called for a null value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52518593/3744182)* for confirmation.  The answer to that question shows a workaround using a custom contract resolver, so reverting to Json.NET might be an option for you in 3.1.  System.Text.Json in contrast [does not make its contract model public](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58926112/3744182).
- If you have applied `EntityConverter` directly to `EventDefinition` using `JsonConverterAttribute`, i.e.:

  ```
  [JsonConverter(typeof(EntityConverter))]
  public class EventDefinition
  {
      public int EventDefinitionId { get; set; }
  }
  ```

  Then the above approach will not work.  In fact there does not appear to be a way to generate a "normal" serialization for an instance of a type to which a converter is applied directly.  Instead you would need to manually write and read each required property inside `Write()` and `Read()`, or write your own reflection code to do so automatically.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NKD0gi).

Comment: In my case I'm stuck with netcore3.1, so I have no access to `public override bool HandleNull => true;` and `JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerOptions)`. Just to confirm, in my case, Will I have to think in a different approach , like dto or ActionFilters to solve my problem?

Comment: @alberto_dev - For `HandleNull` that is correct, the framework is hardcoded to write `null` for a null value in NET Core 3.1.  (Json.NET is the same by the way, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52528455/3744182) for confirmation.)  You will have to adopt a different approach in that version.

Comment: @alberto_dev - As for `JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerOptions)` it would be quite easily to manually create a copy method for `JsonSerializerOptions` in .NET Core 3.1.  I can update my answer with one if you need it.

Comment: @alberto_dev - reverting to Json.NET would also be an option, see [How to force JsonConverter.WriteJson() to be called for a null value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52528455/3744182).  You would need to create a custom contract resolver though, as Json.NET also never invokes a custom converter for a null value.