# How do you handle nulls when serializing to json

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

The default UnixDateTimeConverter in Newtonsoft converts zero values to the Unix Epoch date whereas I am trying to convert it to null by creating a customer convertor.
This works when serializing but not when de-serializing and in particular the WriteJson method in my convertor is not called for nulls.

Is there any way to serialise the null value back to 0 for this field (without converting 0's in other fields)?

The following Linqpad script illustrates the issue.

```
void Main()
{
    var json1 = "{\"LastGood\":1708560000,\"LastBad\":0} ";
     
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json1).Dump("");

    json1.Dump("");
    var json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data).Dump("");
    
}

public class Data
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomUnixDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime? LastGood { get; set; }
    
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomUnixDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime? LastBad { get; set; }

}
// Custom version of UnixDateTimeConverter to deserialize 0 to null and serialize null to 0
public class CustomUnixDateTimeConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.UnixDateTimeConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        base.WriteJson(writer, value ?? 0, serializer);
    }

    public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        object? value = reader.Value;
        if (value != null && (long)value == 0 && objectType == typeof(DateTime?))
            return null;

        return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
    }
}
```

this produces

[image]

whereas I want to last two lines to be the same.

Comment: When I run this in .net fiddle the serialization produces a `null` value for the `LastBad` property, so your `ReadJson` is working correctly. The error is in your `WriteJson`

Comment: [How to force JsonConverter.WriteJson() to be called for a null value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52528455/669576) possibly.

Comment: @001 Thanks. That looks to answer my question, so I'll vote to close this as a dup.

Comment: null and 0 are not the same thing...